# Or and > with CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use a comma in the CSS selector if you are also using > selector?

I want to do something like this, but this syntax didn't work:

```
#id ul > li.class1, li.class2 > a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: why not? but as a note: I don't think the comma does what you think it does.

Comment: yes, and it doesn't seem to work. i guess i ought to rephrase my question - i wanted to know if there was anything like that since i couldn't find anything and just guessed that this syntax could work

Comment: I'd update your question to clearly outline what you expect and what you see. However I think Guffa's answer is probably correct.

Comment: So what you want is like `#id ul > (li.class1 or li.class2) > a` where the child of the `ul` is an `li` of either of those two classes. Is that correct?  CSS can't do that, but maybe you should check out the Sass and Less CSS pre-processors.

Comment: In firefox, you can do `#id ul > :-moz-any(li.class1, li.class2) > a` and in Chrome you can do `#id ul > :-webkit-any(li.class1, li.class2) > a` but there's nothing cross-browser right now. The Selectors 4 draft proposes `#id ul > :matches(li.class1, li.class2) > a` but there's currently no browser support.

Answer (score 4):

The `,` operator only works between complete selectors, not between parts of a selector. You have to repeat all of the selector:

```
#id ul > li.class1 > a, #id ul > li.class2 > a {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: a good assumption (it is what I think OP wanted), but still an assumption at this point. OP should be more clear about what their actual intent is.

Comment: @rlemon: Yes, it's a bit of an assumption, but many answers are. Few questions are completely clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them.

`,` is used to seperate different CSS selections. Whereas `>` is a Child selector and all that kind of things.

Use of comma would seperate each selection and you won't get to the heirarchy if you meant to select a inside each of the element.